# cast to string operator overloading in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, casting, operator-overloading, overloading

I am working on a class that has a method with the following signature:

```
operator const std::string & () const
```

It's documented as "cast to string operator".
I am wondering how to effectively invoke it. Unfortunately the following expression:

```
std::string(foo)
```

produces this error:

```
some_test.cpp:13:41: error: no matching function for call to'
std::basic_string<char>::basic_string(Foo (&)(std::string))'
```

Considering that `foo` is of type `Foo`, declared and instantiated as `Foo foo(std::string(filename))`

being a begginner of C++, this leaves me a bit confused. Any hints on what this means?

Comment: Show the declaration of `foo`, I'm pretty sure you ran afoul of the Most Vexing Parse.

Comment: I updated the post, with the declaration of `foo`

Comment: That declares a function call `foo` returning a `Foo` and taking no arguments (`()`). If you just want a `Foo` object, declare it as `Foo foo;`.

Comment: Sorry, I omitted the argument to the constructor for simplicity. Now I have fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

> `foo` is of type `Foo`, declared and instantiated as `Foo foo(std::string(filename))`

That's a function declaration, interpreting `filename` as the name of a function parameter, equivalent to

```
Foo foo(std::string filename);
```

A variable declaration would look like

```
Foo foo(filename);
```

or, if you needed an explicit conversion (which you probably don't here)

```
Foo foo{std::string(filename)};        // C++11 or later
Foo foo = Foo(std::string(filename));  // historic dialects
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, I omitted the instantiation parameters for the sake of posting a simplification of what I am actually working on. I just fixed it.

Comment: @fstab: I've updated the answer to match your changes.

Comment: I don't understand when you say that it's a function declaration. `filename` is a `const char *`, and what I wanted to do is to convert it to a `std::string` type, before sending it to the `Foo` constructor (object actually will be stored in the `foo` variable)

Comment: @fstab: It's a function declaration because that's how you write a function declaration (with or without `()` around the parameter name). The conversion to `string` can be implicit, so `Foo foo(filename);` will declare the variable you want. If it weren't, then you'd need one of the more complicated forms at the end of the answer.

Comment: I followed your advice and instantiated `foo` with the curly braces. Now I get this error: `undefined reference to Foo::Foo(std::string const&)'`,but I can assure you that I do have that constructor.

Comment: @fstab: "undefined reference" means you've declared the constructor, but not defined it, or not linked with the file that contains the definition.

Answer (score 0):

If you question was about the usage of `operator const std::string & () const`, it is quite simple : this operator is used when you need to convert to a `std::string`. Example :

```
Foo foo(filename);

std::string s = foo; // uses the declared operator const std::string & () const
```